# cocos2d v3: how to CCScene-based touches as well as UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Using various examples throughout this website on how to do objective c, I want to create an app which will require recognition of long presses and single clicks.  The code for my app has the following features (sections omitted for brevity, actual code compiles fine, code below was hand-typed so please not need to point out syntax error):

A base class derived from CCScene (let's call it LongPressHandlingScene)
   a. This class sets up a UILongPressGestureRecognizer during "init" and removes it "onExit"
   b. This class has an method that acts as an event handler for "Long Press" gestures (and it works fine when used by itself)
   b. The rest of this class is the same as any other CCScene class.

```
//LongPressHandlingScene.h
@interface LongPressHandlingScene : CCScene {  
......  
}  
..........  
@end  

//LongPressHandlingScene.m  
@implementation LongPressHandlingScene{  
.............  
}  

-(id)init{  
{  
   if(!(self = [super init]))  
      return nil;  
.........  
   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTouchAction:)];  

   return self;  
}  
..............  
-(void)longTouchAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longTouch{  
..........  
}  

-(void)onExit{  
   NSArray *grs = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] gestureRecognizers];  

   for(UIGestureRecognizers *gesture in grs){  
      if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){  
         [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];  
}  
@end
```

A base class derived from CCSprite (let's call it DragHandlingSprite)
   a. This class overrides touchBegan, touchMoved and touchEnded.  (all work fine when used by themselves inside an CCScene or a CCScene-derived class)
   c. The rest of the class is the same as any other CCSprite class.

```
//DragHandlingSprite.h  
@interface DragHandlingSprite : CCSprite {  
..........  
}  
@end  

//DragHandlingSprite.m  
@implementation DragHandlingSprite {  
..............  
}  

-(void)onEnter{  
   self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  
..............  
}  

-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{  
............  
}  

-(void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{  
   CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];  
   self.position = touchLocation;  
}  

-(void)touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
.............  
}  

// MainScene.h  
@interface MainScene : LongPressHandlingScene{  
.............  
}  

+(MainScene *)scene;  
@end  

// MainScene.m  
@implementation MainScene  

+(MainScene) scene {  
   MainScene *scene = [self node];  

   return scene;  
}  

-(id) init {  
   if(!(self = [super init]))  
      return nil;  

   self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  
...............
   NSArray *itemsArray = ProperlyPopulatedArrayFromSomewhereElse;  
   for(id obj in itemsArray){  
      if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){  
         NSDictionary *vDict = (NSDictionary *)obj;  
         float posX = [[vDcit objectForKey:@"posXKey"] floatValue];  
         float poxY = [[vDict objectForKey:@"posYKey"] floatValue];  
         NSString *name = [vDict objectForKey:@"imageName"];  

         DragHandlingSprite *newImage = [DragHandlingSprite spriteWithImageNamed:name];  
         newImage.name = name;  
         newImage.position = CGPointMake(posX, posY);  

         [self addChild:newImage];  
    }  

@end
```

The issue I'm having after I add one or more "DragHandingSprites" to the "LongPressHandlingScene" are a follows:

Clicking on any "DragHandlingSprite" once works.  Clicking an the same or any other  "DragHandlingSprite" after the first one crashes the app with the error ":

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key'
```

LongPressRecognition works 100% of the times, but as soon as a single click is done once, the same exception as above occurs.

any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. I tried to get it to look nice, but I tried to use the four spaces indicated or ctrl+k or the code button on the menu, but to no avail.

Comment: you tried to add code formatting to a numbered list (1. ...) that's why it didn't format the code

Comment: @LearnCocos2D.  Thx for the edit.  Any ideas why the last portion of the code is not showing up?  (the text for the code is visible when editing the question, but it's just not showing up in the question itself).

Comment: you can scroll the code window

Comment: Awesome, thx.  BTW any chance the answer to my question is in your book?  I already own it, already look for it in there, but maybe I missed something.... maybe..

Comment: no, i didn't cover gesture recognizers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of those that may stumble upon this question looking for an answer, this is what I came up with.

Under normal circumstances, both UILongPressGestureRecognizer (cocoa) and onTouch events (Cocos2d) can co-exists without any issues.  Once both are declared in the same "CCScene" all their respective selectors/event handlers will be called during the "touch" life cycle. This caused the error I mentioned above by allowing all touch/gesture based code to be run.  In my case, some event handlers were deleting info that the UILongPRessGestureRecognizer action selector needed to use and vice-versa, so at some point a 'nil' key was attempted to be worked on and that caused the error.

For this reason I decided to implement an enum based state variable that would keep track of which "touch" state the app was currently in so to prevent code executing out of turn.

```
enum TouchStates {DRAG_BEGAN, DRAG_MOVED, DRAG_ENDED, LONG_TOUCH_BEGAN, LONG_TOUCH_ENDED, DEFAULT};  
enum TouchStates touchState;
........  

-(id)init{  
   ................  
   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTouchAction:)];  
   ............  
}

-(void)longTouchAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longTouch{  
   if(/*[touchState is the correct one to do something here]*/){  
      if(longTouch.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){  
         touchState = LONG_TOUCH_BEGAN;
         .............
         //DO WHAT'S NECESSARY HERE
         .............  
   }
   // Do something similar for the "UIGestureRecongizerEnded" flag  
}

-(void)onTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{  
   if(/*[touchState is the correct one to do something here]*/){  
      touchState = DRAG_BEGAN;
      ..............  
      //DO WHAT'S NECESSARY HERE  
      ...............
}  

// Do something similar for the onTouchMoved and onTouchEnded event handlers.
```